# I got from $x=5$ to $x^2=25$ using invertible algebraic manipulations. Where did the solution change from $5$ to $\pm5$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers

Consider the very simple equation:
$$x=5 \text{  where  }x\in \mathbb{R}\tag1$$
Using algebraic manipulations restricted to exact equivalences only we can rearrange it in the following way:
$$\iff e^{ln(x)}=e^{ln(5)} \tag2$$
$$\iff e^{ln(x^{2*0.5})}=e^{ln(5^{2*0.5})} \tag3$$
$$\iff e^{0.5*ln(x^2)}=e^{0.5*ln(5^2)} \tag4$$
$$\iff e^{0.5^{ln(x^2)}}=e^{0.5^{ln(5^2)}} \tag5$$
$$\iff \sqrt {e} ^{log_\sqrt{e}(x^2)\over log_\sqrt{e}(e)}=\sqrt {e} ^{log_\sqrt{e}(5^2)\over log_\sqrt{e}(e)} \tag6$$
$$\iff \sqrt {e} ^{log_\sqrt{e}(x^2)}-\sqrt {e} ^{ log_\sqrt{e}(e)}=\sqrt {e} ^{log_\sqrt{e}(5^2)}-\sqrt {e} ^{ log_\sqrt{e}(e)} \tag7$$
$$\iff x^2-e=5^2-e \tag8$$
$$\iff x^2=25 \tag9$$

In $(1)$ we get the set of values that satisfy the equation $x=\{5\}$, while for $(9)$ we get $x=\{5,-5\}$.

Wait what? I only used algebraic manipulations restricted to exact equivalences only and all manipulations are invertible. In fact I can read everything bottom to top and every algebraic manipulation is valid.

This begs the question: In which line did the set of solutions change and why?

Comment: $\ln(x^{2 \times 0,5})$ is defined for $x > 0$ only, whereas $0,5 \ln(x^2)$ is defined for every $x \neq 0$. Therefore you cannot replace the first expression by the second one.

Comment: `e^(ln(x^2)) = e^(ln(5^2))` does not reverse back to `e^(ln(x)) = e^(ln(5))` because you add your extraneous root of -5 at that step.

Comment: $e^{0.5*ln(x^2)}=e^{0.5^{ln(x^2)}}$.This is not true. Put $x=1$ then $e^0=e^1$ . What?

Comment: The problem is that $\ln(x^2) = 2 \ln |x|$.

Comment: So https://mathinsight.org/logarithm_basics#log_power is incorrect?@eyeballfrog

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Hi, is the decimal comma still widely used in mathematics in your country? Just curious.

Comment: @ryang https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator

Comment: @tempdevnova I know.-) My query has two specifics: "still", "mathematics". Your previous post indicates that you may be in a country that uses the decimal comma, so the fact that you used the decimal point suggests that perhaps in mathematics the latter may be more common?

Comment: @ryang "My query has two specifics: "still", "mathematics"." What exactly did you mean by that?

Comment: @ryang You mean writing "$0,5$" rather than $0.5$ ? Yes, we use rather $0,5$ in France.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Ah, thanks. $\quad$ tempev noa: I said "still" because I don't want to assume that the wikipedia article is the most up-to-date.

Comment: @ryang If I am not mistaken all countries which generally use , instead of . also do so in maths.

Comment: In Germany I have never seen anyone use the the decimal point in maths, except for me. The only reason I do is because I generally am active on english speaking websites. Fun fact: If you buy a Texas Intruments calculator in Germany it will use the decimal comma instead of decimal point. @ryang

Comment: That's what I thought: you are catering to those of us the decimal-point folks. P.S. The decimal-point versus decimal-comma is [a changeable setting](https://www.fixya.com/support/t10445721-casio_calculator_decimal_changed) on handheld calculators.

Comment: @ryang Ahh good to know I can actually change it. What I also just thought about: I think that we won't see a shift toward the decimal point anytime soon (at least in German) simply because the comma is deeply engrained in our language. E.g. for 3.14 we say "Drei **Komma** Eins Vier" ("three **comma** one four) as opposed to "three **point** one four" in English

Comment: That's an interesting point! P.S. No need to change, the comma is very easy to adapt to (unlike a certain system that starts with I ;) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}e^{\ln(x^{2\times0.5})}=e^{\ln(5^{2\times0.5})} \tag3\\
\iff e^{0.5\ln(x^2)}=e^{0.5\ln(5^2)} \tag4\end{align}

This equivalence is false, because on the reals, $$x^{2\times\frac12}= (x^2)^\frac12\iff x\ge0.$$ Correction:
\begin{align}&e^{\ln(x^{2\times0.5})}=e^{\ln(5^{2\times0.5})}\tag3\\\iff {}&e^{0.5\ln(x^2)}=e^{0.5\ln(5^2)} \quad\text{and}\quad x\ge0\tag{4r}.\end{align}